# PostGIS ST_asGeoJSON on specific columns and not all the row columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I have a table with hundred of columns.
I would like to write a single SELECT to get the GeoJSON string returning ONLY specific columns values (geometry and some others fields, but not all the columns values).

If I run:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(d.*)
FROM   mytable d 
WHERE  d.id = 76025);
```

It works, but if I want only some fields like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(d.wkb_geometry, d.info, d.address)
FROM   mytable d 
WHERE  d.id = 76025);
```

Obviously the St_asGeoJSON doesn't work because it has row as parameter and not a list of fields.
How can I get only those 3 columns in the resulting geoJSON WRITING A SINGLE STATEMENT?

Comment: You may try using `json_build_object`.

Few examples are here :
https://www.sqliz.com/postgresql-ref/json_build_object/

Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple using subquery:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(p.*) 
FROM   (SELECT d.wkb_geometry, d.info, d.address
        FROM   mytable d 
        WHERE  d.id = 76025) AS p;
```